# Existing Infra of Kubernetes with Docker EE Licensing

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am a bit confused about Docker EE. In my case I have fully working setup of Kubernetes. It has few dev,test application containers, and now we want to move for production containers(App) which are client facing so developers were talking about docker EE for prod. Now how it will affect my existing kubernetes infrastructure? Do I need to go for any additional configuration for my kubernetes, or it's just way of creation of container image by developer part will change?
As existing Kubernetes infra maintaining part is anything changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DockerEE has its own way to install and setup kubernetes.

Its simpler than the usual kubernetes setup in my opinion.  But one thing i noticed in dockeree, kubelet is running as a container managed by swarm.  Most if not all kubernetes control plane components are managed by swarm not systemd.

Comment: ,Thank for the quick response,...But in my case I already have Kubernetes infra now do I need to create another one using\for Docker EE????

Comment: Or can I use Container created with Docker EE with my existing Kubernetes cluster...

Comment: Yes! You can always use any docker image created by any image builder as long as it is OCI compliant and deploy to kubernetes cluster.  You cam even use the docker engine of dockeree and use the upstream kubernetes to manage the kubernetes cluster. All fine.  But checkout the kubernetes docker compatible version.  I think 18.03/18.06 is compatible with kubernetes upstream.